# Difference between the clock and the high-resolution timer

Tags: time, clock, hardware-test

I was trying to make a test for my PC using Geekbench 4 but after the test end, it showing no results and tell me:

> Geekbench has detected a 5.86s difference between the clock (164s) and the high-resolution timer (158s) on your system. Since this difference can affect benchmark results, Geekbench will not display the benchmark results.

Anyone can help me with this please?

Thanks @Byte Commander and here are the results:
[image]

Comment: Can you run `sudo hwclock --compare` in a terminal and let it run for maybe a minute, so that you have a couple of data points, and [edit] your question to add its output?

Comment: I used Geekbench on Linux mint 18.3 on the same PC with the same Bios setup and it's worked 100%, why on Ubuntu not?  https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/6264062